# PHP: Stacking an array over multiple columns in a table

Tags: php, html, css

I have an interesting problem, seems like it would have been solved long ago but can't find anything.

I have a simple array, variable length.

I need to put the array in a table BUT only X columns wide.  Meaning, if the array has 25 values, and I only want 3 columns, there will be 2 columns of 11 and 1 column of 3 (the remainder).

Like this (each number represents a value in a table cell):

```
1    12    23
2    13    24
3    14    25
4    15
5    16
6    17
7    18
8    19
9    20
10   21
11   22
```

I've spent all day afternoon this, seems like it would be simple, but either my game is off today or it's harder than I think.

Of course, no problem going horizontally, easy, but vertically is the requirement and I never know the size of the array and number of columns can vary.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Why not 2 columns of 10 and the third of 5 ?

Comment: I can imagine this to be a bit tricky simply because, as long as the left columns are equal in size and are longer than the right-most column, that would be a valid solution. That is to say, two columns of 10 and one of 5 would fit the requirements, two columns of 12 and one of 1 would fit, two columns of 9 and one of 7 would fit...

Comment: so is the number of columns and the length of a column an argument for a function that should "print" it?

Comment: What is the rule how many items go into one column? What's the maximum column count that is allowed? This looks like a simple problem you can solve in one foreach loop ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks nanocv! Here's your solution changed up a bit to directly answer the question:

```
$numberOfColumns = 3;
$myArray = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25);

$arrayLength = count($myArray); // 25
$columnLength = ceil($arrayLength / $numberOfColumns); // 9

for($i=0; $i<$columnLength; $i++) {

    $table .= '<tr>';

    for ($j = 0; $j < $numberOfColumns; $j++) {

        $arrayIndex = $j * $columnLength + $i;

        if($arrayIndex < $arrayLength) {
            $table .= '<td>' . $myArray[$arrayIndex] . '</td>';
        } else {
            $table .= '<td></td>'; // render empty cells
        }

    }

    $table .= '</tr>';
}

echo '<table border="1">' . $table . '</table>';
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know you wanted to build a HTML table with the data. I'm happy you could find the solution to your problem! Please, consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 8):

In the case you want the last column to have as many elements as posible to fit the other columns (the most dynamic case for this problem), this would be a solution:

```
<?php

$numberOfColumns = 3;
$myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25];

$arrayLength = count($myArray); // 25
$columnLength = ceil($arrayLength / $numberOfColumns); // 9

for ($i = 0; $i < $columnLength; $i++) {

  for ($j = 0; $j < $numberOfColumns; $j++) {

    $arrayIndex = $j * $columnLength + $i;
    if ($arrayIndex < $arrayLength) {
      echo $myArray[$arrayIndex] . " ";
    }

  }

  echo '<br>';
}
```

This is the output in my browser:

[image]

Comment: @BillKervaski It's a very good practice to accept the right answer in order to support users motivation. Please consider doing that here :)

Answer (score 1):

You will don't believe it.

All you need is just HTML and CSS - https://jsfiddle.net/wz9kp6x0/

```
<div class="xtable">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  ...
  <div>24</div>
  <div>25</div>
</div>
```

and

```
.xtable {
  column-count: 3;
}
```

See also docs: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_multiple_columns.asp

Enjoy! ;)